# Update data from API fetch request with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling to find a way to update and manipulate the fetched data. I want the {data.servings} to increase by 1 every time I click the **Plus** button. Even though the rendered data is **a number of servings** but it's data type is **STRING** so I figured a way to assign its value to a variable called **portions** and convert it to **number** like below. However, I can't update or manipulate it. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

```js
const handleData = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(()=>{
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setData())
    },[url])


    const handleIncrement = (e) =>{
      let portions = parseInt(e.currentTarget.previousSibling.innterText)
    }
    return (
      <>
        <Minus />
        //the output of {data.servings} is 2 but it's data type is STRING
        <p>{data.servings}</p>
        <Plus onClick={handleIncrement}/>
      </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this handleIncrement  function

```
const handleIncrement = () => {
  let copyData = { ...data };
  copyData.servings = `${parseInt(copyData.servings) + 1}`;
  setData(copyData);
};
```